# Как передать значения в js файл

Tags: javascript, jquery

В js не силен, может быть вопрос и банальный, но...

Есть график на js, в него мне нужно передать мои данные.

Код моей страницы:

```html
<canvas id="lineChart" height="150"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    ChartJs.init();
  });
</script>

<script src="/assets/js/page/chart.demo.js"></script>
```

Код файла **chart.demo.js**

```js
var handleRenderChart = function() {
 Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Arial';
 
 var ctx = document.getElementById('lineChart');
 var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
   labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
   datasets: [{
    color: PRIMARY_COLOR,
     //other linies
    label: 'Total Sales',
    data: [12, 19, 4, 5, 2, 3]
   }]
  },
  options: {
   scales: {
    yAxes: [{
     ticks: {
      beginAtZero:true
     }
    }]
   }
  }
 });
 };
 
 
 /* Controller  */
var ChartJs = function () {
 "use strict";
 
 return {
  //main function
  init: function () {
   handleRenderChart();
  }
 };
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Я хочу, если это возможно, передавать как то тут **ChartJs.init();** параметры **labels**, **label**, **data**

Или как иначе можно передать данные чтобы график отобразился с моими данными?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Когда добавляли код, подключите там же Jquery(слева в панели)

Comment: @Netahaki подключил. но в нем нет смысла, так как я не подключал все js скрипты которые связанные с графиком

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужно что-то такое:

```
<canvas id="lineChart" height="150"></canvas>
<script src="/assets/js/page/chart.demo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
  var data = [12, 19, 4, 5, 2, 3]
  var label = 'Total Sales'
  ChartJs.init(labels, data, label);
  });
</script>
```

А в `chart.demo.js` примерно так:

```
var handleRenderChart = function(labels, data, label) {
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Arial';

    var ctx = document.getElementById('lineChart');
    var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                color: PRIMARY_COLOR,
              //other linies
                label: label,
                data: data
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
 };


 /* Controller  */
var ChartJs = function () {
    "use strict";

    return {
        //main function
        init: function (labels, data, label) {
            handleRenderChart(labels, data, label);
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: сделал как вы указали. но данные не передались. получаю **undefinded**

Comment: @Денис Потыкаю сейчас на `codepen`-е, дополню ответ

Comment: @Денис Странно, у меня в `codepen` все данные передаются. Дополните пожалуйста вам вопрос исправленным кодом.

Comment: @Денис Скажите, а ваш `Controller` располагается в другом файле? Или может быть его код находится до объявления `var handleRenderChat`?

Comment: контроллер объявляется в том же файле, и после объявления переменной. вроде бы дополнять больше нечего... jquery 3.2.1

Comment: В каком месте вы проверяете данные? Где делаете `console.log`?

Comment: тут сделал log : `var handleRenderChart = function(labels, data, label) { console.log(labels); }` получил - **undefined**

Comment: @Денис Дополните пожалуйста код в вопросе, чтобы я увидел что вы всё правильно поменяли. Мне кажется, что вы не поменяли контроллер(не передаете данные из контроллера), по другому я это объяснить не могу. Либо не поменяли место инициализации, там где `ChartJS.init()`

Comment: вы правы. я не в ту функцию отправил данные. спасибо большое! ваше решение работает.

Comment: @Денис Всегда пожалуйста :)